# ElementaryOS on Macbook Pro 2012 does not start any more

Tags: macbook, startup

I have a strange combination of behaviour on my MacBook Pro 2012 that has been running fine until recently.

- After a holiday, I tried to start it and nothing happened. I heard some quiet startup fan noise in an interval of about 2 seconds. This noise appeared faster (about 1 second interval) when I pressed the power key.
- At first I thought of a hardware problem. I opened the back, and detached the battery to see if it was taking too much from the power supply, but it didn't change the behaviour.
- I asked the web and found the "power cycle" key combination (detach power cable, then press and keep pressed power button for 10+ seconds, then re-attach power cable while keeping the button pressed for 10 seconds). After 10+4 seconds, I heard a startup noise with the fans going maximum fast and loud, and the Apple startup sound. But the display remained black. After around 30 seconds, the system turned off and then automatically re-started, looping the ca. 30 seconds startup attempts.
- Keeping the Alt-Button pressed while starting succeeded in accessing the Boot menu. I can see my installation there and I can select it. But afterwards, the display remains black and the computer turns down after about 30 seconds.
- I can also attach an elementaryOS-Installation-USB stick, and select in in the Boot menu. Then, I will see some Logging on the screen, but again, the system will be turning down after about 30 seconds.

I am still not sure whether this is more a hardware or a software problem. I can access the startup phase of elementaryOS, at least when choosing the USB stick. Probably also the elementaryOS installed on my harddisk starts to load, only it does not show any logging. So I made to believe this is an elementary problem.

- Has anyone experienced a similar behaviour?
- Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Or even how to fix it?

I won't be shy to try to re-install elementaryOS, once I know how to save my data. Thank you!

## EDIT 1 :

Pressing ESC for around 2.5 seconds when the Apple startup sound occurred, I was able to enter the GRUB boot selection and chose the recovery mode there. This showed me some boot logs which I filmed off screen. The boot logs looked fine until they were suddenly ending. Since they didn't end at the very same line each time I filmed them, I was starting to think about the RAM being a problem here.

I cannot unmount the hard wired RAM. So I am going to try to read the SDD with a 24 PIN to SATA / USB adapter. I am going to update once I know about the state of the SDD.

## EDIT 2 :

As suggested by Vlad, I had the memtest running, for over 8 hours. Found 0 errors.

Comment: Might be a shot in the dark, but try reinserting the RAM (remove battery, pop the RAM out, put them back in, put battery back)

Comment: @Vlad Good idea. I would actually like to do that, but the RAM is hard wired. See my Edit 1. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a Retina MacBook? You could try to make a memtest USB drive and boot from it to check the RAM https://www.memtest86.com/tech_creating-linux-mac.html

Comment: @Vlad Good idea again. Had the memtest running today for 8 hours. Found 0 errors.